# How to remove text after last space?

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I have NSString like "My name is". I want to remove text after coming last space. Means whatever text come after last space i want to remove that. Answer will be then My name. Please help me if any one knows how to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get My name form your string use the following

```
NSString *str = @"My name is";
NSRange range = [str rangeOfString:@" " options:NSBackwardsSearch];
NSString *str2 = [str substringToIndex:range.location];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *str = @"My Name is";    
NSArray *ary = [[NSArray alloc]init];    
ary = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
str = [ary objectAtIndex:0];
str= [str stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@",[ary objectAtIndex:1]];
```

Answer (score 0):

easiest way to do this is to use "`NSMutableString`" instead of "`NSString`" and then you can do the ["`deleteCharactersInRange:`" method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/deleteCharactersInRange%3a), where the "range" parameter is the range of characters you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code
For Example

```
  NSString *foo = @" untrimmed string  ";
  NSString *trimmed = [foo stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: This does not answer his question!

Answer (score 0):

This will work although not the best way

```
NSString *myName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"My Name is."];
NSArray *splitComponents = [myName componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
myName = [myName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",[splitComponents lastObject]] withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
NSArray *arr = [yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

Then omit last object and create new string.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString * str=@"My name is";
     NSArray *parameters = [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" "]];
    NSLog(@"%@",[parameters description]);

    NSRange rangeOfDash = [ str rangeOfString:[parameters lastObject]];
    NSString * output = (rangeOfDash.location != NSNotFound) ? [str substringToIndex:rangeOfDash.location-1] : nil;

     NSLog(@"answer%@",output);
```